# Form Action Workflow "canceled by System Account"

Tags: workflow, custom-form

I've created a button, around which I've wrapped a form action that calls a custom form action. Problem is, it keeps erroring off with:

```
User ID         Date Occurred     Event Type         Duration   Description  

System Account  1/20/2011 1:54 PM Error                         Custom Form Action 1 failed to start. 
System Account  1/20/2011 1:54 PM Workflow Canceled     435,612 Workflow Custom Form Action 1 was canceled by System Account. 
System Account  1/20/2011 1:47 PM Error                         Custom Form Action 1 failed to start. 
System Account  1/20/2011 1:47 PM Workflow Canceled  -3,396,280 Workflow Custom Form Action 1 was canceled by System Account. 
System Account  1/20/2011 1:46 PM Error                         Custom Form Action 1 failed to start. 
System Account  1/20/2011 1:46 PM Workflow Canceled  -1,970,134 Workflow Custom Form Action 1 was canceled by System Account. 
System Account  1/20/2011 1:29 PM Error                         Custom Form Action 1 failed to start. 
System Account  1/20/2011 1:29 PM Workflow Canceled   3,714,748 Workflow Custom Form Action 1 was canceled by System Account.
```

I've included several records to show that the duration is different every time. Why is that? Why is it negative sometimes?

I've even deleted it and created a new one that only writes to the history, and I get the same error.

The page was created from a site template that included the Custom Form Actions. Could that have anything to do with it?

I have other lists in this site collection that use Form Action Workflows without this error.

Thoughts? Links? Suggestions?

Comment: Bump. From my online research, it appears that workflows cannot run under the System Account. Fine. But, how do I tell SPD to quit doing that for this list?

It doesn't seem to matter what I do... all form actions for this list are set to run under System Account, which causes them to fail.

Ideas?

Comment: Another thing I just learned about this situation: When I first import the site, the custom form action workflows work. If I edit them or even open and "Finish" them, they start erroring with the "System Account" issue.

Also, perhaps this all has to do with the WFCONFIG.XML, because clicking "Finish"—if no edits are made—leaves the XOML as the current version, but a new version of the WFCONFIG.XML is saved. Right-click > View History reveals multiple versions. Choosing to Restore the 1.0 version actually doesn't do that. It created a new version (presumably a copy of the 1.0). Fail.

Comment: What version of SharePoint is this? Does it have latest CUs installed?

Comment: @Alex: WSS; and probably not. ;) Will look into that. Ultimately rebuilt the project in production and reassembled all the hooks. Working now. I suspect production is on a different SP that test. Something else I'll be looking into when I have the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, I had to re-build the site in production and build the form action workflows there.

As Alex suggested above, I suspect that issue has to do with CUs or disparate Service Packs.

But to rebuild, I had to:

1. Remove the form actions from the test version
2. Change all of the SelectParameters to reference ListName instead of ListID, then replace the GUID with the Display Name of the list
3. Export all the webparts
4. Export all the lists
5. Create a blank site in production
6. Import the lists into the blank site
7. Copy the webpart pages from test to production
8. Add the webparts back to the zones in production
9. Copy the webpart connections section from SPD into Dreamweaver and swap out all of the "g_" IDs, the paste it into the webpart page in production
10. Find/replace all of "g_" IDs in the connection links
11. Rebuild the form action workflows

All is working well now.

Answer (score 0):

Under the list settings within the GUI, do you still show multiple versions of this workflow within the Workflow settings?  I'm not sure if having a lot of variations of the same workflow is the ticket, but I like to delete all of the versions that aren't currently being used.

Comment: No. No multiple versions of the WF... but there was one named "Testing"... removed that one. Didn't help.

Comment: Also, the reason there are no versions of the workflow there is probably because these are not list workflows, but rather custom form actions... not tied to a list.